# Mysql 2 columns data in a group

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table:

> id  a  b
>   1   1  2
>   2   2  1
>   3   2  1
>   4   3  2
>   5   2  3

col a b [1 2] is equal to col a b [2 1], so i'd like these data into a group, how can i get a result something looks like:

> id a b
>    5 2 3 
>    3 2 1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableName
WHERE  (LEAST(a, b), GREATEST(a, b), id) in 
(
    SELECT  LEAST(a, b) as x, 
            GREATEST(a, b) as y, 
            MAX(ID) as id
    FROM    TableName 
    GROUP   BY x, y
)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d408/4)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select max(id), least(a, b) as a, greatest(a, b) as b
from t
group by least(a, b), greatest(a, b);
```

This will actually produce the values `(1, 2)` and `(2, 3)` for your data, if that is ok.

If you want to fetch the data in the original order, then you can use the above as a subquery and join on id:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select max(id) as maxid, least(a, b) as a, greatest(a, b) as b
      from t
      group by least(a, b), greatest(a, b)
     ) tmax
     t.id = tmax.maxid;
```